# How can I generate multiple OSGi bundles from a single Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix

The basic problem is as such: I've got a project that already uses multiple Maven modules for various sub-projects. However, one of the modules (the core module) could itself be split into multiple OSGi bundles when created. This is due to the core module containing several optional dependencies, each of which have isolated Java packages where they're required. For instance, support for JSON input files are optional as they require the optional dependencies from Jackson. The classes that rely on the Jackson dependencies are all isolated to certain `json` packages within the module. Thus, in theory, I could create a minimal bundle from core that doesn't include the packages that rely on optional dependencies.

Normally, I'd simply split up this module into more Maven modules to make life easier for creating bundles via Felix's maven-bundle-plugin. The problem here is that I still want to create a core JAR for non-OSGi users who don't want to have to include several extra JARs just to use optional functionality (which requires they provide the optional dependencies on the class path as it is). Not only that, but I don't wish to have to split up this module into more modules as it makes development on the project more tedious for the developers as well, especially when we're already splitting up code into proper package-based modules as it is.

The way we were trying to use OSGi already was to make the API module a fragment host (in order to allow it to load a provider bundle without requiring OSGi support), then make the other bundles use said fragment host. This seemed to work well for the smaller modules outside of core, but for core, we wanted to be able to provide multiple bundles from a single module so that optional dependencies wouldn't be required in the bundle itself. As it stands, for plugins, we already have a mechanism for scanning them and ignoring plugins that don't have all the required classes to load them (e.g., if a plugin requires a JPA provider but the JPA API is not available, that plugin isn't loaded). Once we can successfully split up the core module into multiple bundles, I can use declarative services as the plugin method in an OSGi environment (instead of the default class path JAR scanning mechanism in place for normal Java environments), so that isn't an issue.

Is there any way to do all this using Felix's maven-bundle-plugin? Or will I have to use the assembly plugin to copy subsets of the module where bundles can be generated from? Or will I have to resort to writing an Ant script (or Maven plugin) to do this? We've tried using separate Maven modules that simply import the core module as a dependency and generating a bundle from there, but the resultant bundle is always empty regardless of import/export package settings and embed dependencies.

Or, is there a better way to do this? We already use the `<optional>true</optional>` configuration for the optional dependencies, yet the Felix plugin doesn't seem to care about that and imports all of those dependencies anyways without using the optional attribute.

Comment: You really can't build multiple artifacts per project using Maven. That's just not how Maven works, and you'll be fighting it the whole way. Also the way you're using optional package imports sounds really strange and unnecessary; you might want to describe the motivation for this in more detail, so that a better solution can be found.

Comment: The optional dependencies are used for certain plugins that are loaded on demand on startup. If a plugin is missing dependencies, that plugin is not added to the list of available plugins. If it helps, the project in question is Log4j version 2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is what I'm ending up doing to accomplish this. I'm using the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to copy the binaries I need and filtering out the classes I don't want to include using the `<fileSets/>` element similar to the `<fileset/>` element in Ant.

Using the generated directories for each assembly, I'm using the [maven-bundle-plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) along with the `<buildDirectory/>` configuration option to specify where the bundle's class files are located.

It's not ideal, but it's better than writing an Ant script for a Maven project!